# CSS selector for an img element with class

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<a href="/">
  <img class="myClass" src="someImg.jpg" />
</a>
```

I tried to apply hover effect on image using:

```
img .myClass:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The selector `img .myClass` will select an element with a class of `myClass` that is [a descendant](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) of an `img` element. But since `img` elements can't contain descendant elements, that doesn't make sense.

You want to select an `img` element with a class of `myClass`, therefore you need to remove the space:

```
img.myClass:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms ease-in;
  vertical-align: top;
}
img.myClass:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="myClass" src="//placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```